# Indented SelectList Items

Tags: asp.net-mvc, indentation, selectlist

I have a List of Categories (entities) with each of them having parents. Here is the Model for the category :

```
  public class Category
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }

        public int? ParentId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual Category Parent { get; set; }
    }
```

I need to populate a SelectList such that the Parents come first and the childrens go indented Like:

- Category 1

  - SubCategory 1
  - SubCategory 2
- Category 2

I have to use this selectlist to poulate a dropdown in the edit and update forms. How do I go about doing this? clientside? serverside?

Thanks for any help you can offer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This got me thinking about implementing this without the dependency of an `interface`, which I still think is reasonable. Here is an alternative solution using an extension method that does not require an `interface` to be implemented.

**Extension Method**

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns a single-selection select element containing the options specified in the items parameter.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The type of elements in the collection.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="helper">The class being extended.</param>
    /// <param name="items">The collection of items used to populate the drop down list.</param>
    /// <param name="parentItemsPredicate">A function to determine which elements are considered as parents.</param>
    /// <param name="parentChildAssociationPredicate">A function to determine the children of a given parent.</param>
    /// <param name="dataValueField">The value for the element.</param>
    /// <param name="dataTextField">The display text for the value.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static MvcHtmlString DropDownGroupList<T>(
        this HtmlHelper helper,
        IEnumerable<T> items,
        Func<T, bool> parentItemsPredicate,
        Func<T, T, bool> parentChildAssociationPredicate,
        string dataValueField,
        string dataTextField)
    {
        var html = new StringBuilder("<select>");

        foreach (var item in items.Where(parentItemsPredicate))
        {
            html.Append(string.Format("<optgroup label=\"{0}\">", item.GetType().GetProperty(dataTextField).GetValue(item, null)));

            foreach (var child in items.Where(x => parentChildAssociationPredicate(x, item)))
            {
                var childType = child.GetType();

                html.Append(string.Format("<option value=\"{0}\">{1}</option>", childType.GetProperty(dataValueField).GetValue(child, null), childType.GetProperty(dataTextField).GetValue(child, null)));
            }

            html.Append("</optgroup>");
        }

        html.Append("</select>");

        return new MvcHtmlString(html.ToString());
    }
}
```

**Usage** *based on your `Category` `class`*

```
@this.Html.DropDownGroupList(YourCollection, x => !x.ParentId.HasValue, (x, y) => { return x.ParentId.Equals(y.CategoryId); }, "CategoryId", "Name")
```

By the time I finished writing this post I wasn't so sure this was all that valuable but thought I'd post it anyways.

As you can see, your `class` must know the id of it's parent and the display name of both the child and parent should use the same property as indicated by the `dataTextField` parameter. So, essentially, your `class` needs the properties: Id, ParentId, and Name and you use the `Func<T, bool>` and `Func<T, T, bool>` parameters to determine relationships.

Don't forget to add in the necessary validation!

Answer (score 1):

I would do this server-side using `optgroup` like this in `razor` syntax.

```
<select>
@foreach(var parent in categories.Where(x => !x.ParentId.HasValue)
{
    <optgroup label="@parent.Name">
    @foreach(var child in categories.Where(x => x.ParentId.Equals(parent.CategoryId))
    {
        <option value="@child.CategoryId">@child.Name</option>
    }
    </optgroup>
}
</select>
```

I would also make this an extension methods so it would like the other available HTML helper methods.

**Edit**

---

An extension method could accept a collection of items which implement a simple interface like this:

```
public interface IGroupable
{
    int Id { get; set; }

    string Name { get; set; }

    int? ParentId { get; set; }
}

public class Category : IGroupable
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }

    public int? ParentId { get; set; }    //implements IGroupable.ParentId
    public string Name { get; set; }    //implements IGroupable.Name

    public virtual Category Parent { get; set; }

    #region [IGroupable Specific  Implementation]

    public int Id { get { return this.CategoryId; } }

    #endregion
}

public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static MvcHtmlString DropDownGroupList(this HtmlHelper helper, IEnumerable<IGroupable> items)
    {
        var html = new StringBuilder("<select>");

        foreach (var item in items.Where(x => !x.ParentId.HasValue))
        {
            html.Append(string.Format("<optgroup label=\"{0}\">", item.Name));

            foreach(var child in items.Where(x => x.ParentId.Equals(item.Id)))
            {
                html.Append(string.Format("<option value=\"{0}\">{1}</option>", child.Id, child.Name));
            }

            html.Append("</optgroup>");
        }

        html.Append("</select>");

        return new MvcHtmlString(html.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: some braces are off in the code you posted. I understand the idea, but I am unable to implement it. This is the error in the HttpResponse `CS1977: Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation without first casting it to a delegate or expression tree type`

Comment: @codetantra hmmm I don't see any braces off here but I did add a `static` class to contain the extension method.

Comment: @codetantra I've applied the `IGroupable` `interface` to your `Category` `class`. By doing this, you can now pass an `IEnumerable<Category>` to the `DropDownGroupList` extension method. You could just change `IGroupable.Id` to `IGroupable.CategoryId` to save you from having the extra property but IMO this implementation suggests it is a little more generic. i.e. does not suggest use with just categories only.

Comment: So i can just use it as `@Html.DropDownGroupList(Categories)`? where Categories is IEnumerable<Category>.

Comment: @codetantra that's correct and you can add any overloads from there that you see fit. If you then come across another `class`/`entity` that you need to display the same way all you need to do is implement the `IGroupable` `interface` on the `class` as well.

Comment: I changed all instances of Id to CategoryId and am using `@Html.DropDownGroupList(ViewBag.Categories)`. However it is giving an error regarding an extension method cannot be dynamically dispatched. I got to cast the parameters as IEnumerable<IGroupable> explicitly?

Comment: @codetantra hmmm...this should work if the extension method is being called in a regular view. Are you doing anything out of the ordinary?

Comment: its in a partial view. The controller calls : `ViewBag.Categories = _unitOfWork.CategoryRepository.Get();` and the DropDown is in a Ajax Form on the partial view.

Comment: @codetantra actually I believe your problem is because you are using the `ViewBag` which contains `dynamic` properties. If you can make your views strongly typed, that would be ideal. This way you can pass your collection to the view from the controller and it will be the correct type. To make your view strongly typed, add the following declaration `@model IEnumerable<IGrouping>` to the view in question. Or you can cast your collection as you mentioned.

Comment: @codetantra **After you get this working**. I just wanted to mention that IMO it is better to have models for each of your views and in this case, your `IEnumerable<IGrouping>` would simply be a property on the view model. Now since you are using a partial view for rendering the drop down, the partial view could be strongly typed to `IEnumerable<IGrouping>` if that's all the information it needs to render. Then you just pass in the property on the view model to the partial view.